# The Bootstrap Dropdown menu ends up as a button and series of navigation items

Tags: drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement the Bootstrap dropdown for a language selection menu. I thought I followed the format Bootstrap, and other tutorials, laid out but I just end up with a button and series of links next to or underneath the button.

Firstly, I have tried a the Bootstrap 4 documentation. I have tried all similar StackOverflow answers and the tutorials at https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp as well as some Youtube videos. For whatever reason(I'm hoping someone can enlighten me) nothing has worked.

Here's a link to my fiddle for reference. https://jsfiddle.net/rescriba/9a7bmdkf/30/

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown button</button>  
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="flagDiv" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" title="English" href="#">EN</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" title="Deutsch" href="#">DE</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" title="Française" href="#">FR</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" title="Italiano" href="#">IT</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" title="Español" href="#">ES</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" title="Português" href="#">BR</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" title="русский" href="#">RU</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" title="中国" href="#">SCN</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" title="日本" href="#">JP</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" title="한국의" href="#">KR</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't including a bootstrap CSS theme in that JSFiddle. Is that your issue?

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Don't use W3 Schools, refer to the official Bootstrap docs. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/

Comment: Well, that's egg on my face. Thanks very much.